# Joining table based on Month in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union, yearmonth

here i have 2 table that i wanted to join.
i have two table. which is table1 and table2. i only able to union between these two tables. Below is my current output table.

[image: using union to join the table]

However, my expected output is should be like this:

| year | month | usage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 7 | 432.738 |
| 2022 | 8 | 552.306 |
| 2022 | 9 | 3148.40500 |

i wanted to join table1 and table2 by sum of **usage** column based on the month.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do SUM/GROUP BY from your query.

```
select year, month, sum(usage) as usage
from (
  YOUR QUERY IN THE PICTURE
) as q
group by year, month
```

For the future, paste the query as text, not as an image

Comment: Hi sir, thank you so much for your help. I manage to get my expected output. Really appreciate your help.